# How to use TMX data in Qt [C++ Game]

Tags: c++, qt, tmx

I'm learning how to do things in Qt creator, and downloaded ["Tiled"](http://www.mapeditor.org/) which is a tiled map creator that outputs a .TMX file.  I created a simple map with a couple different colored tiles.

Now, in Qt Creator 2.4.1 [latest version... it says "Based on Qt 4.7.4 (32-bit)"], I'd like to be able to use it in a Qt C++ project.  Some Googling got me to find a TMX Parser [http://code.google.com/p/tmx-parser/] but I can't get the source code [I downloaded Silk SVN to SVN Checkout the code, but I'm not able to set up a proxy], but in any case TMX is supposed to be like XML, and Qt has its own XML parser, right?

My end goal is to be able to somehow use my own tiled maps in a simple game, coded in Qt Creator with my C++ skills.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like you are lucky. The source you needed is BSD licenced.

Program is build over the internal libtitled library. 
So you could just use it in your project.

Just download the Tiled source code, and compile it in your Qt Creator.
Look at tmxviewer project as an example of integrating libtitled in QT application.